# how to assign values to undefined objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var data = {};
data.info.id = "alpha";
```

This logs to the console: "`TypeError: data.info is undefined`".

Well that's great and all but I need to store a value in `data.info.id`. Isn't that what objects are supposed to do?

This should produce an object that looks like this:

```
data: {
  info: {
    id: "alpha"
  }
}
```

Is `data.info = {}` really a necessary step?

In response to Patrick Evans - that's an unrelated question.

Comment: Yes it is. Otherwise `data.info` is, wait for it, `undefined`. Objects don't automatically get properties when you try to access them. That'd create all kinds of chaos.

Comment: Mike C - fair enough. Reply so I can give you Best Answer

Comment: Who is Patrick Evans, and what does he have to do with your question? Comments should be addressed with comments, not edits to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is another way. That's putting the `info`-object directly in the `data`-object like this:

```js
var data = {
  info: {}
}
data.info.id = "alpha";

console.log(data);
```